# making fullscreen div animate down from top

Tags: css, html, mootools, fullscreen, webkit-transition

I have a fullscreen overlay, I have it set up in jfiddle currently so it just fades in
http://jsfiddle.net/9NJP9/1/
What I'd like it to do instead of fade is animate down from the top of the screen down to the bottom; slides down.  My site is longer then the screen height, when the button is clicked though I don't really want it to slide down from the top of the entire site all the way to the bottom of the page, just from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen, and then stay there even when someone scrolls.  I'm just not sure how to manipulate the css to do this.

Any help I can get with this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please add all the prefixes - other browsers besides webkit support `transition`.

Comment: You can't calculate the window height in CSS, so this would require script. You can get away with width by simply using: #div { width: 100%; } However, I would strongly recommend using a JS framework, like jQuery. Achieving seemingly complex animations and calculations on the window is a breeze with this. http://jquery.com/ Once you look at jQuery, examine the following and see how it benefits you: $(window).width(); $(window).height(); $("#div").animate({ /* properties here. */ }); By the way, your jsFiddle doesn't seem to be working for me. Good luck.
Michael.

Comment: ...also, cross-borwser with jQuery. Your CSS transitions won't work in IE or older browsers.

Comment: so I'm not 100% sure how to do this with Jquery, but I just poked around their site and it looks like with $(window).height() and .slideDown()  I'm not 100 percent sure how to set it up.  I'd imagine setting the css to display:none and then setting the height like var overlayheieght = $(window).height(); $(#fullscreen).height(overlayheight); and then call the slide down like $(#fullscreen).slideDown("slow");  does that sound right at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/9NJP9/8/

For the slide down effect, instead of changing the `opacity` from 0 to 1, you could change the `top` property from something like `-500px` or `-50%` to `0`. In the fiddle, I've set it to transition from `-100%` to `0`. Also, instead of CSS for just webkit browsers, you need to make your effect **cross-browser compatible**. I've modified the CSS accordingly.

```
.fullscreen_hide {
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    -ms-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #141414;
}

.fullscreen_show {
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    -ms-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #141414;
}
```

As @MichaelGiovanniPumo pointed out, you should try out [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) as well. It makes life much more comfortable. :)

Comment: so the only problem with this is it doesn't stick to the screen while it scrolls.  I'd assume you do this by position fixed but then the z-index becomes invalid.

Comment: this is a great solution but if you have lots of content add this to help with the scrolling but I like this solution regardless.   overflow: scroll;